# Actix Websocket Lobby always session length of 1

Tags: rust, websocket, actix-web

I have the problem that the sessions of the [lobby](https://github.com/antholeole/actix-sockets/blob/main/src/lobby.rs) example is always 1.
I added a minimal working example [here](https://github.com/SamTV12345/podgrabv2/tree/feature/websockets).

When connecting this function is executed

```rust
#[get("/ws")]
pub async fn start_connection(req: HttpRequest, stream: Payload, lobby: Data<Addr<Lobby>>)
    -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let ws = WsConn::new( lobby.get_ref().clone());
    let resp = ws::start(ws, &req, stream)?;
    Ok(resp)
}

#[get("/ws/send")]
pub async fn send_message_to_user(lobby: Data<Addr<Lobby>>) ->impl Responder{
    lobby.get_ref().send(BroadcastMessage { message: "Broadcast".to_string() }).await.unwrap();

    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Message sent")
}
```

The send_message_to_user function should send a broadcast message to every open session. The weird thing is that when connecting to the [lobby](https://github.com/SamTV12345/podgrabv2/blob/feature/websockets/src/models/web_socket_message.rs) it always has a length of 1 when opening multiple browser windows/tabs.

How to reproduce:

- Open the project.
- Start the Rust server with Cargo
- Start the React project with npm run dev
- Go to localhost:5173/ui
- You should see the output in the Rust console.